# Completion sources not recognized by nvim-cmp

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, lsp

I recently transitioned from LanguageClient-neovim to built-in lsp support and completion using omnifunc. However I was enticed by the promise of auto-imports and completion snippets including function arguments, so I've been trying to integrate nvim-cmp. It requires a snippet engine so I installed vsnip, which seems to be working fine. However autocomplete is not working.

No matter what I do, it won't recognize any of the completion sources I try to install.

I don't see any errors at any point, it just seems to be silently failing; autocomplete does not appear when I type.

Here is the output from running `CmpStatus`:

```
# unknown source names
- nvim_lsp
```

I'm not sure what other debugging options are available to me at this point other than print-debugging the cmp plugin.

I have installed the following relevant plugins using pathogen:

- cmp-nvim-lsp
- cmp-vsnip
- nvim-cmp
- nvim-lspconfig
- vim-vsnip
- vim-vsnip-integ

I have gradually pared down my config file to a (hopefully reasonably) minimal representation, including removing all of the sources and mappings I tried to configure for nvim-cmp except lsp support:

```
syntax on

filetype plugin indent on

set runtimepath=$HOME/.config/vim,$VIMRUNTIME

execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

map / <leader>

" lsp """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if has('nvim')
lua << EOF

vim.o.completeopt = 'menu,menuone,noselect'

local nvim_lsp = require('lspconfig')

local cmp = require('cmp')

cmp.setup({
        snippet = {
                expand = function(args)
                        vim.fn['vsnip#anonymous'](args.body)
                end,
        },
        mapping = {
                --['<C-d>'] = cmp.mapping(cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4), { 'i', 'c' }),
                --['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping(cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4), { 'i', 'c' }),
                --['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping(cmp.mapping.complete(), { 'i', 'c' }),
                --['<C-y>'] = cmp.config.disable, -- Specify `cmp.config.disable` if you want to remove the default `<C-y>` mapping.
                --['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping({
                --      i = cmp.mapping.abort(),
                --      c = cmp.mapping.close(),
                --}),
                --['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
        },
        sources = cmp.config.sources({
                { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
        }),
})

local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').update_capabilities(capabilities)

local servers = { 'metals', 'tsserver', 'rls', 'vimls' }
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
        nvim_lsp[lsp].setup {
                capabilities = capabilities,
        }
end

EOF
endif
" end lsp """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

Here is the output from `nvim --version`:

```
:$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.5.0
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compilation: clang -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNVIM_TS_HAS_SET_MATCH_LIMIT -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -I/tmp/neovim-20210702-21950-fs4dxz/neovim-0.5.0/build/config -I/tmp/neovim-20210702-21950-fs4dxz/neovim-0.5.0/src -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/tmp/neovim-20210702-21950-fs4dxz/neovim-0.5.0/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tmp/neovim-20210702-21950-fs4dxz/neovim-0.5.0/build/include
Compiled by brew@iMac-Pro

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.5.0/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

Comment: My first thought would be to check the plugin docs or ask the plugin maintainers. They can probably guide you towards what you need or how to debug something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the way that the completion sources are structured. Pathogen is not able to load them. I resolved the issue by switching to packer.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the minimal structure you're using in packer?  I'm getting the same error, with packer.